# org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException:Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Optional'

Tags: spring, option-type, path-parameter

For the first time i am using Optional in Rest Web Service to make a Path Parameter as optional.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/hosts","/hosts/{name}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Object> getHosts(@PathVariable Optional<String> name) {
    if(name.isPresent()) {
        return service.getHosts(name.get());
    } else {
        return service.getHosts(null);
    }
}
```

When i use the API without the parameter, it works fine.

But when i give the parameter, it throws the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Optional'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Optional]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:47)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:603)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
```

I have spent quite a time debugging this but could't get past this error. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add "mvc:annotation-driven/>  to your xml file to make it work.